# QHBoxLayout(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt

I'm creating a layout for a GUI that is supposed to have a QVBoxLayout for main layout and QHBoxLayout for sublayout, but for some reason it gives me this error.

Here is the code:

```
class Application(QtGui.QMainWindow):

        err1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
        reset = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(Application, self).__init__()
          self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)
          self.setWindowTitle('IPv6 traffic generator')
          PlotWidget(self)
          self.createwidgets()

        def createwidgets(self):


          self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self) 
          self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

          self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
          self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.mainLayout)

             ---- creating widgets ----

          self.hLayout.addWidget(self.label2)
          self.hLayout.addWidget(self.menubutton1)
          self.hLayout.addWidget(self.label3)
          self.hLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
          self.hLayout.addWidget(self.button3)
          self.mainLayout.setLayout(self.hLayout)
          self.mainLayout.show()
```

Comment: Provide the full error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done wrong is that , your providing QHLayout with another Layout object  while it accepts only a QWidget.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/stackoverflow/QtVlayout.py", line 37, in <module>
    myapp = Application()
  File "C:/stackoverflow/QtVlayout.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.createwidgets()
  File "C:/stackoverflow/QtVlayout.py", line 23, in createwidgets
    self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.mainLayout)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
    QHBoxLayout(): too many arguments
    QHBoxLayout(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'
```

So to achieve what your trying to do :

```
self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)
```

and remove

```
self.mainLayout.show()
```

This should solve the issue .

Comment: The OP's example also tries to call `show()` on the main layout, which will give another (different) error.

Answer (score 0):

The proto type of construct a QLayout is

```
def __init__(self, QWidget=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__ with multiple overloads
    pass
```

so, you need to construct like this:

```
self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
```

Comment: using self as a Qwidget will work fine , but it will disrupt the parent child hierarchy. and you still need to use the addLayout method to add the sub-layout.

Comment: @TheCreator232. In this case, even using `self` won't work properly, because it is a `QMainWindow`, which already has a layout.